# How to pass Request to Controller constructor in Symfony2?

Tags: symfony

I want to pass the Request object to a controller constructor, like this:

```
public function __construct(Request $request){
        $this->startGameSession($request);
}
```

But I get an error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MyController::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request, none given...
```

The same works perfectly on actions, but not in __construct.

Comment: Why would you do that?

Comment: I want to check a session variable if it exists, and set if not. And for that I WANT to get the session from the request.

Comment: Don't do it.  Even if you think you have a good reason don't do it.  If you want something to happen before the controller is called then look at kernel listeners.

Answer (score 10):

In the latest versions(>3.4 - not really sure since when) of Symfony controllers are registered as services.
https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html

Just pass **RequestStack $requestStack** as parameter in the constructor.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $request = $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
        //do something with the $request

    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

To use `request` instance from `__constructor` you need to define the controller as service and inject `request_stack` service instead ([Ref.](https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller/service.html)).

> A controller can be defined as a service in the same way as any other class.

```
namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        //do something with $requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
    }
}
```

Then you can define it as a service as follow (since Symfony 3.3 this might not be necessary because autowiring):

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    service_controller:
        class: AppBundle\Controller\ServiceController
        arguments: ['@request_stack']
```

You can also route to the service by using the same notation when defining the route `_controller` value. To refer to a controller that's defined as a service, use the single colon (:) notation.:

```
# app/config/routing.yml
index:
    path: /index
    defaults: { _controller: service_controller:indexAction }
```

That's it all!

Comment: Lately the controllers are defined as services, so the service definition is not required anymore. At least in 3.4 works. That means it's just enough to pass the RequestStack $requestStack as parameter in the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

When a Symfony kernel is handling a request, it is trying to resolve a controller from the request.

```
namespace Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver;

...

public function getController(Request $request)
{
    if (!$controller = $request->attributes->get('_controller')) {
        if (null !== $this->logger) {
            $this->logger->warning('Unable to look for the controller as the "_controller" parameter is missing.');
        }

        return false;
    }

    if (is_array($controller)) {
        return $controller;
    }

    if (is_object($controller)) {
        if (method_exists($controller, '__invoke')) {
            return $controller;
        }

        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('Controller "%s" for URI "%s" is not callable.', get_class($controller), $request->getPathInfo()));
    }

    if (false === strpos($controller, ':')) {
        if (method_exists($controller, '__invoke')) {
            return $this->instantiateController($controller);
        } elseif (function_exists($controller)) {
            return $controller;
        }
    }

    $callable = $this->createController($controller);

    if (!is_callable($callable)) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException(sprintf('The controller for URI "%s" is not callable. %s', $request->getPathInfo(), $this->getControllerError($callable)));
    }

    return $callable;
}
```

All things a controller can be are:

- Array callables (object/method or class/static method combinations).
- Invokable objects (objects with the magic method `__invoke()`, like anonymous
  functions, which are an instance of `\Closure` ).
- Classes of invokable objects.
- Regular functions.
- Any other controller that is provided as a string should be of the pattern `class::method`, `BundleName:ControllerName:actionName` or `service_id:methodName`.

After method `getController()` returns the controller, response is generated from the controller and passed arguments.

So, you can't have direct access to controller construction, because Symfony is creating the controller from the Request object.